# Scatter Graph click event firing on point below

Tags: highcharts

Using Highcharts scatter graph. We have a graph consisting of around 10,000 points. We have some points which are "special" (between 5-10) and formatted with a marker with a radius of around 30px. Underneath that marker can be several points that have a radius of 2. We are using mouse tracking and hover states to show which point you are over but there are many times that the mouse is considered closer and therefore hovering on a point below the formatted larger marker.

We have the formatted points in a separate series which is layered on top of the normal smaller marker series

We need click events on all points but need the larger formatted markers click event to take precedent.

**EDIT:**

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvfpekgo/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [[43933,1001], [43935,1002],[43937,1003],[44000,1000], [44000,1001],[43999,1000], [75000,2000], [80000,2500], [85000,3000], [13000,3500]],
    marker:{
        radius:1,
      symbol:'*'
    },
    type:'scatter'
  },
  {
    data: [[43934,1000], [52503,1500], [57177,2000], [69658,2500], [97031,3000], [119931,3500],[137133,4000], [154175,4500]],
    marker:{
        radius:20,
      symbol:'*'
    },
    type:'scatter'
  }
 ]
});
```

Under the first larger marker there are 6 smaller markers. We need to prevent the hover state from activating on those that are covered by the larger marker

Comment: Hi @David Perry, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek,Thanks for getting back to me. I have update the question with a jsfiddle

Comment: But what is the exact problem? The click event is fired for every hovered point: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/recxn5uw/

Comment: The problem is that we do not want the event to fire on the points if they're overlapped by the formatted marker

Comment: Ok, but do you want to have the hover effect with tooltip on them?

Comment: No, we only have a highlight on hover to show which point you are over. custom tooltips are shown on click with actions on them. So we end up with people performing an action on the point behind the intended point. 

Because we have such a dense scatter graph in areas it can be very hard to hover on the correct point as there can be several points behind

Comment: So if you have any connection between the points, you can trigger an event at a larger point. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2o36r7j0/